# html5 saving clicked a href link into localstorage and redirect to same link on each visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, local-storage

First need to store a href url in localstorage and visitor are to be redirected to same url which is stored in localstorage on every visit on website until visitor clicks on another link and changes the link.

If visitor can change link, the same process should repeat and visitor should be redirected to the new url which is stored in localstorage on every visit on website until visitor can click on another link and change link.

1) problem is in function stored url in localstorage as visitor is redirected to the previous / old url which is stored in cache before the selection of a new link, even if he is clicking another link??

2) second problem is it auto refresh and reload `stored link` on each and every visit on website and `stored link` cache cloudn't be delete or change when click to new link old cache showing in chrome->resources->localstorage?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/edgematrix/vfz38s9z/1/)

Comment: Coockies aren't enough ?

Comment: no i need to do with localstorage?

Comment: kindly solve this issue i need to updated on website